# Array Index our of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, dataframe, loops, processing

I am trying to create a 2d array from a table of the following [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rajyellow46/wine-quality), unfortunately when I try iterate through my table to set the array values to be the same as those of the table accordingly I keep receiving the following error:

```
6497 total rows in table
13 total columns in table
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Column 13 does not exist.
```

The following is my code. I am using processing in java mode by the way.

```
Table table;
float[][] variablesDataframe = new float[12][6497];

table = loadTable("/data/winequalityN.csv", "header"); //Importing our dataset
println(table.getRowCount() + " total rows in table"); //Print the number of rows in the table
println(table.getColumnCount() + " total columns in table"); //Print the number of columns in the table

for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < table.getRowCount(); j++){
    variablesDataframe[i][j] = table.getFloat(i + 1, j);    
  }
}
```

The reason I skip over the first column (i + 1) is because it's dtype String/Object and I only want the floats which is the rest of the dataset in my 2d Array.

If anyone can help me achieve this or fix the code would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you show us your Table class?

Comment: Well, sure? you declared `variablesDataframe` as being `float[12][6497]`, so when you try to put something into `variablesDataframep[12]`, which doesn't exist (only index 0 through 11 exist), you get an error. Make sure your table and dataframe are sized to match each other before you start your loop.

Comment: Your `table` has 13 columns. `getFloat` is being called with `i + 1` so the values range from 1 to 13 and there's no index 13 in `table`. Also for `variablesDataframe[i][j]` the index `i` goes from 0 to 12, but there is no index 12 in that array

Comment: He wanted to ignore the 1st table's column. Your `i` for loop need to be like `i < table.getColumnCount() -1`, so that when you call `table.getFloat(i + 1, j)`, it won't overflow

Answer (score 1):

Your variableDataframe array is defined as [12][6497]

In your code, your first for loop initializes i from 0 and it will keep iterating till it hits 13. So, in all you will get 13 values of i.

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < table.getRowCount(); j++){
    variablesDataframe[i][j] = table.getFloat(i + 1, j);    
  }
}
```

Since you want to skip the first row, do this instead

```
 for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount()-1; i++){ 
      for (int j = 0; j < table.getRowCount()-1; j++){
        variablesDataframe[i][j] = table.getFloat(i+1, j); 
      }
 }
```

This will ensure that you are skipping the first row and you will only have 12 values in the array. Same applies to the rows as well.

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean. However, when I use the code you wrote I still get the same error. I am using processing perhaps it has something to do with that?

Comment: What kind of processing ?

Comment: processing 3.5.4, but nvm I worked it out with my teacher. Thank you anyways for all the help much appreciated.